# iphone setting and reading state UISwitch

Tags: iphone, uiswitch

I have a view in which its objects are set from a database and likewise saved to a database. The UITextViews are working great, but I cannot seem to find out how to set the state of a UISwitch.

I can change it in the IB but that isnt what I need.  The record in the DB has a 0 or 1 boolean.  So if the field is true then I want to set the state of the UISwitch to ON.

Also when I save the record, I need to be able to look at the value on the view, and thus set the field on my table.

thanks for any help!!

**EDIT:  This is what I have done so far:**

***.h  file***

```
@interface UserEdit : UIViewController {


    IBOutlet UISwitch *male;

}


@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UISwitch *male;
```

***.m file***

```
@synthesize male;


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [male SetOn:NO];


}
```

the app dumps when it hits the SetOn line above

I also need to be able not only set the value, but read it too

Answer (score 44):

You can set the state of a [UISwitch](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISwitch_Class/Reference/Reference.html) either via the `on` or `setOn:animated:` methods, depending on your requirement.

e.g.: `[yourUISwitch setOn:YES];`

Check the Setting the Off/On State section of the [UISwitch Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISwitch_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for more info.

**UPDATE**

As per the docs, you can *read* the value via `[yourUISwitch isOn];`

Comment: please see additional info above.

Comment: @Mark I've updated my answer. (That said, **you should use `setOn`, not `SetOn`**, as you've used in the update to your question.)

Comment: can someone tell me what I did wrong?  I know it must be wrong but no idea why!

Comment: @Mark As per my comment, you need to use `setOn`, not `SetOn`. (The case is significant.)

Comment: thank you!  @JustSid simply said I wrote it wrong that didnt help at all but @middapaka comments saved the day!  thank you!!!!

Answer (score 2):

You can do it the following way:

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//


#import "ViewController.h"


@interface ViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *mySwitch;

- (IBAction)switchChanged:(id)sender;

@end


@implementation ViewController

- (IBAction)switchChanged:(id)sender
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:self.mySwitch.on forKey:@"SwitchState"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.mySwitch.on = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"SwitchState"];

}

@end
```

Comment: I've tried your code,did not work, I' want to store UISwitchState to remember username ,password in my App

Comment: First of all, I wouldn't use this method to store passwords, since they can be read (it stores info in a plist file). There are more appropriate ways to store passwords. When you say it didn't work, can you elaborate on that (have you done debugging to see where it didn't work)? Kind regards.

Answer (score 1):

There is the swift version code to setting and reading UISwitch's state

```
    //Change switch state
    self.mSwitchAccept.setOn(true, animated: true)
    //Get the switch state
    let switchState : Bool = self.mSwitchAccept.on
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to set a UISwitch you have to use this `[yourSwitch setOn: YES animated: YES];`

In order to read the UISwitch you need to retrieve it by the state of the switch which is a boolean type `NSLog(@"Switch state :%d", [yourSwitch isOn]);`